# How would I get this specific paragraph class textContents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, roblox, jsdom

To give some context, I'm trying to get summary of a data type directly from example being: [Axes](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/Axes). I've been using [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) and this is how I thought I should go about things:

```
const Jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = Jsdom;
const Axios = require('axios');

async function Data_descriptions(Data_types) {
    let Descriptions = [];

    for (let Index = 0; Index < Data_types.length; Index++) {
        const Data_type = Data_types[Index];
        const Description = await Axios.get(
            `https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/${Data_type}`,
            {
                responseType : 'document'
            }
        ).then(Response => Response.data).then(Data => new JSDOM(Data)).then(Body => Array.from( Body.window.document.querySelectorAll('span.MuiTypography-root.jss15') ));

        Descriptions.push(Description);
    }

    return Descriptions;
}

Data_descriptions(['Axes']).then(Descriptions => {
    console.log( Descriptions [ 0 ] );
    
    Descriptions [ 0 ].forEach(
        Element => console.log( `Text: ${Element.text} | Content: ${Element.textContent} | Inner: ${Element.innerText}` )
    );
})
```

However, this is exporting to the console a lot of the elements that are within parameters. Except for the one I need specifically. Just to clarify this is what the summary element I'm trying to get shows on the webpage:

> The 'Axes' datatype is for the 'ArcHandles' class to control which rotation axes are currently enabled.

This is coming from this Html: [Html Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQDqN.png)

When I execute the current script, I get this output:

```
Text: undefined | Content: Beta | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Collapse Sidebar | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Axes | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Show Deprecated | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: new(axes: Tuple) | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: axes: Tuple | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Tuple | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: X: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Y: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Z: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Top: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Bottom: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Left: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Right: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Back: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Front: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: axes | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: :  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Tuple | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: boolean | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content:  | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: On this page | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: ©2022 Roblox Corporation. All rights reserved. | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Company | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: About Roblox | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Accessibility | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Careers | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Technology | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Terms of Service | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Privacy Policy | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Parents | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Developer | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Creator Dashboard | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Community | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Announcements | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Social Media | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Twitter | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Facebook | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: LinkedIn | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: Instagram | Inner: undefined
Text: undefined | Content: YouTube | Inner: undefined

[
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {},
  HTMLSpanElement {}, HTMLSpanElement {}
]
```

Comment: Can you include in the question 1) what the data you receive from the api looks like (a small example response, not the link to the documentation) and 2) what data specifically you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by looking in the text for a keyword or phrase.

Or even an entire paragraph if you want.

```
let class = 'span.MuiTypography-root.jss15';

let target = document.querySelectorAll(class)
    .filter(node => node.innerText.includes(
    "The 'Axes' datatype is for the 'ArcHandles' class to control which rotation axes are currently enabled."
))[0];
```

Comment: I did try that but that didn't work, and I think this has to do with how the html class is being used on the site. Also isn't quite what I'm trying to do because there are other pages that I'm also trying to get their summaries. As I can tell these pages have the same layout for the html classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had found that Roblox on their documentation site has a script in their html that has a json string of everything I'll need.

````
const Axios = require('axios');
const Cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function Description ( Data_types ) {
    let Descriptions = [ ];

    for ( let Index = 0; Index < Data_types.length; Index++ ) {
        const Data_type = Data_types[ Index ];
        const Description = await Axios.get(
            `https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/${ Data_type }`
        ).then( Response => {
            const $ = Cheerio.load( Response.data, { xmlMode: true } );
            const Script = $( 'script:not( [ src ] )' ).get().filter( Script => Script.attribs.id === '__NEXT_DATA__' )[ 0 ];
            const Script_data = JSON.parse( Script.children[ 0 ].data );

            return Script_data.props.pageProps.data.apiReference.constructors[ 0 ].description;
        } );

        Descriptions.push( Description );
    }

    return Descriptions;
}

Description(['Axes']).then(Descriptions => {
    console.log( Descriptions );
})```
````